# Is it possible to have multiple simultaneous profiles in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I know it's possible to have multiple profiles in Firefox, but is it possible, under one user, to run two different profiles at the same time? The same way it's possible with Chrome and multiple people/personas?

Comment: Possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/316465/how-to-start-firefox-using-two-different-profiles-at-the-same-time?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Just go to `about:profiles` (type it in the address bar or create a bookmark for easy access).